# Django pagination по URL: постраничная навигация

Tags: url, pagination, django

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите как сделать постраничную навигацию в таком формате:

```
http://site.ru/queries/page2/
```

вместо:

```
http://site.ru/queries/?page=2
```

Нужно дважды прописывать в urls.py?

```
url(r'^queries/$', QueryListActive.as_view(), name='query_list'),
url(r'^queries/page(?P<page>\d+)/$', QueryListActive.as_view(), name='query_list')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, нужно дважды прописывать url, но вообще лучше так не делать. Считается (и поисковики это любят), что один ресурс (список объектов) должен быть доступен по одному URL, а фильтры и паджинация - это параметры этого ресурса.